# Http request configuration url must be a string. Received: undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just moved my upload function from controller (where it was working as it should) to factory and it sudenly stopped working. I'm keep getting this error, but i don't know/understand where the problem is

```
angular.js:13550 Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string.  Received: undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$http/badreq?p0=undefined
    at angular.js:68
    at $http (angular.js:11194)
    at uploadWithAngular (ng-file-upload.js:91)
    at sendHttp (ng-file-upload.js:144)
    at upload (ng-file-upload.js:330)
    at Scope.$scope.uploadDocument (locationsCtrl.js:131)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14432), <anonymous>:4:338)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15485)
    at callback (angular.js:25018)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17229)
```

This is my upload document function in controller

```
$scope.uploadDocument = function(file) {
    if($scope.documentName.length > 4) {
        $scope.errorMsg = '';
        file.upload = Upload.upload( documentsFactory.uploadDocument(
            $scope.id_location,
            $scope.documentName,
            $scope.documentDescription,
            file,
            $scope.locationUniqueId
        ));
        file.upload.then(function (response) {
            $scope.documentName = $scope.documentDescription = $scope.userFile = '';
            documentsFactory.getDocuments($scope.id_location).then(function (data) {
                $scope.documents = data;
            });
            $timeout(function () {
                file.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function (response) {
            if (response.status > 0)
                $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function (evt) {
            // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
            file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
        });
    }else{
        $scope.errorMsg = 'Name should be at least 5 chars long';
    }
};
```

And this is my factory

```
factory.uploadDocument = function(id_location, name, description, file, locationUniqueId){
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/rest/api/document/documents',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            data: {
                id_location: id_location,
                name: name,
                description: description,
                userFile: file,
                locationUniqueId: locationUniqueId
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            return response.data;
        },function errorCallback(response){
            console.log('Error uploading documents: ' + response);
        });
    };
```

UPDATE:
This is working example if i make "upload request" in my controller

```
 file.upload = Upload.upload({
    url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/rest/api/document/documents/',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: {
        id_location: $scope.id_location,
        name: $scope.documentName,
        description: $scope.documentDescription,
        userFile: file,
        locationUniqueId: $scope.locationUniqueId
    }
});
```

If you need any additional inflammations please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Comment: If you log "$location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/rest/api/document/documents'" before the $http call, whats the output?

Comment: it's ok (http://myapp.com/rest/api/document/documents/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the error stack:

From [ng-file-upload repository.](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/dist/ng-file-upload.js)

```
this.upload = function (config, internal) {
```

which is called by you there

```
 Upload.upload( documentsFactory.uploadDocument(
        $scope.id_location,
        $scope.documentName,
        $scope.documentDescription,
        file,
        $scope.locationUniqueId
    ));
```

line 330

```
return sendHttp(config);
```

line 144

```
uploadWithAngular();
```

line 91

```
$http(config).then(function (r) {
```

Where the error gets thrown. It looks like Upload.upload doesn't accept a promise, but a config for the $http call.

---

EDIT

What about returning the config object?

```
factory.uploadDocument = function(id_location, name, description, file, locationUniqueId){
    return {
        method: 'POST',
        url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/rest/api/document/documents',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: {
            id_location: id_location,
            name: name,
            description: description,
            userFile: file,
            locationUniqueId: locationUniqueId
        }
    }
};
```

The best idea would be to move Upload to the factory and return the promise.

```
factory.uploadDocument = function(id_location, name, description, file, locationUniqueId){
    return Upload.upload({
        method: 'POST',
        url: $location.protocol() + '://' + $location.host() + '/rest/api/document/documents',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: {
            id_location: id_location,
            name: name,
            description: description,
            userFile: file,
            locationUniqueId: locationUniqueId
        }
    });
```

Comment: hm, thx for that, but can you please also make an example, how should i prepare data for calling Upload.upload({}) function or it's impossible to do this via factory?

Comment: i have added the working code, how it looks like my controller function for uploading, if i make request in controller

Comment: I've edited my answer as well. Take a look. Returning only the config object from your service might solve the problem.

Comment: I've made another edit. I'd move Upload to the factory, and only return it's promise to the controller.